# Yii2 Creating Dynamic Navigation using database

Tags: php, menu, yii2, navbar

I'm implementing a dynamic navbar in Yii2 which displays a dropdown menu picking items from the database. Now, the problem is that when I call the function in which I fill the array, the system crash with the error:

> "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

since it doesn't find the variable with the array of items. I don't know which controller should pass the arguments to the main view, I just need an array of all items in a data model (i.e. Course).

I've tried out with this but still doesn't work.

```
  /* @var $courses \app\models\Course[] */
```

layouts/main

```
function items($courses)
{
    $items = [];
    foreach ($courses as $course) {
        array_push($items, ['label' => $course->title, 'url' => 
        Url::to(['course', 'id' => $course->id])]);
    }
    return $items;
}

$menuItems = [
// other items ...
    'label' => 'Courses', 'items' => items($courses)
];

echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'uk-navbar-item'],
    'encodeLabels' => false,
    'items' => $menuItems
 ]);
```

How can I pass the `$courses` variable to the layouts/main view? Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Where do you make `$my_courses` array?

Comment: It is just a name, I edited maybe now it is more clear.

Comment: have you placed the `function items()` inside the view ?

Comment: Yes, it is as in the code above.

Comment: that is not the right way to do it and where it the `$courses` coming from that you are passing as a parameter to the `items()` function ? is ti coming from the controller action ? please provide the complete code reference, it would be better if you add your controller code via pastebin link if it is too large

Comment: As I wrote the problem is indeed the fact that I don't know where to pass that variable since layouts/main view has not an associate controller.

Comment: i understand that but where is the `$courses` coming from ? looks to be a database model rows collection but where are you querying it ?

Comment: i am talking about at this line `'label' => 'Courses', 'items' => items($courses)`

Comment: $courses doesn't come from anywhere since I don't know where to pass something to the main view. I guess I should do something like: $courses = Course::find()->all() in some controller but still don't know. I thought it could have been just importing the array like this:  /* @var $courses \app\models\Course[] */ but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extract this code into widget:

```
class MainMenu extends Widget {

    public function run() {
        echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'uk-navbar-item'],
            'encodeLabels' => false,
            'items' => $this->getItems(),
        ]);
    }

    protected function getItems() {
        return [
            // other items ...
            ['label' => 'Courses', 'items' => $this->getCoursesItems()],
        ];
    }

    protected function getCoursesItems() {
        $items = [];
        foreach (Course::find()->all() as $course) {
            $items[] = [
                'label' => $course->title,
                'url' => Url::to(['/course', 'id' => $course->id]),
            ];
        }
        return $items;
    }
}
```

Then in your layout you're just calling:

```
<?= MainMenu::widget() ?>
```

In this way you can keep your controller and view clean.

Comment: Could be a good idea but result in a system crash with the error: "The 'label' option is required."